# Cómo puedo sobreponer un canvas sobre otro?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, canvas

Estoy realizando una implementación de un canvas en ReactJS que carga un documento pdf, en este caso quiero crear un canvas que quede sobre el primer canvas para poder trazar sobre él sin tocar el canvas que renderiza el documento pdf.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<div>
            <PDFDocumentWrapper>
                <div style={{position:'relative'}}>
                    {!pdfDocument && <span>Loading...</span>}
                    <canvas ref={canvasRef}
                        onMouseDown={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                const canvas = canvasRef.current
                                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
                                handleMouseDown(nativeEvent, ctx);
                            }}
                        onMouseMove={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                const canvas = canvasRef.current
                                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
                                handleMouseMove(nativeEvent, ctx);
                            }}

                        onMouseUp={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                const canvas = canvasRef.current
                                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
                                handleMouseUp(nativeEvent, ctx);
                            }
                        } />
                    {Boolean(pdfDocument && pdfDocument.numPages) && (
                        <nav>
                            <ul className="pager">
                                <li className="previous">
                                    <button disabled={page === 1} onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>
                                        Previous
              </button>
                                </li>
                                <li className="next">
                                    <button
                                        disabled={page === pdfDocument.numPages}
                                        onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}
                                    >
                                        Next
              </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div style={{position:'absolute'}}>
                    <PDFDocumentWrapper>
                    <canvas style={{position:'absolute'}} width={200} height={200}></canvas>
                    </PDFDocumentWrapper>
                </div>

            </PDFDocumentWrapper>

        </div>

const PDFDocumentWrapper = styled.div`
  canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
`;
```

Cómo podría posicionar el segundo canvas sobre el primero y que tome las mismas dimensiones de éste? o existe una forma de dibujar sobre el primer canvas y eliminar un dibujo en concreto sin limpiar todo el canvas?